# How to create a jagged parchment border in Flutter

Tags: flutter, customclipper

I'm trying to recreate an aspect of this [Old Parchment CSS effect](https://codepen.io/AgnusDei/pen/NWPbOxL) using native Flutter widgets.

I have got the texture and box-shadow working, but I would like to modify my InputDecoration widgets to give jagged box decorations like this

[image]

The website is using an SVG filter called "wavy2" to achieve the jagged edge:

```
<svg>
  <filter id="wavy2">
    <feTurbulence x="0" y="0" baseFrequency="0.02" numOctaves="5" seed="1" />
    <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="20" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

To recreate this I've looked at Stackoverflow which led to [Flutter's docs on CustomClipper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html), this looks like the route but I'm not sure how to recreate that SVG functionality.

Looking up the attributes of InputDecorator it seems likely it won't support this at all. I would need to nest my text entry fields in Containers so I can dress them with BoxDecoration widgets, giving me access to CustomClipper.

That's fine, but I'm still stuck. Apparently, there are built-in attributes of SVG to create these randomising effect and I don't know how to recreate that using a CustomClipper. I'd love a fully explained solution to upskill me.